# windows logo key optimization in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, menu

How do I make the XFCE whisker menu launch with the Windows logo key in xubuntu like other operating systems?

Comment: In the Linux world, you can refer to that key as the Super key :)

Comment: should I edit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little step-by-step to do that.

1. Go to *Settings>Keyboard>Application Shortcuts*.
2. Click on *Add*.
3. For the Command type in `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu`.
4. Click *OK*.
5. It will now ask for the key, and press either Super Key you want to
   pop it up with.

If you are using the Applications Menu like I am, the command would
    then be `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu`.

**Note:** You might want to look through the keyboard shortcuts that might be using the Super Key you chose.  If you try to do those other shortcuts, it could always bring the menu up as well as how the other shortcut works.

Hope this helps!